# why index only scan is too costly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I have this for query for a table of a size of 2 700 000 rows in Heroku Postgres 12.16:

```
SELECT 1 AS one
FROM "users"
WHERE (
    external_id = 18
    AND (email = 'user@example.com'
         OR uuid = '779c7963-67b2-43ea-b19b-028759a146dc'))
LIMIT 1
```

It takes 1497.968 ms to execute.

With `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` it returns the following:

```
"Limit  (cost=1000.11..41646.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=491.141..1497.948 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.11..82292.01 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=491.140..1497.946 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 1"
"        Workers Launched: 1"
"        ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using index_users_on_external_id_and_email_and_uuid on users  (cost=0.11..81291.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=953.762..953.762 rows=0 loops=2)"
"              Index Cond: (external_id = 18)"
"              Filter: (((email)::text = 'user@example.com'::text) OR ((uuid)::text = '779c7963-67b2-43ea-b19b-028759a146dc'::text))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1111474"
"              Heap Fetches: 3238"
"Planning Time: 0.139 ms"
"Execution Time: 1497.968 ms"
```

I see the total cost is too high (81291.81) and I suspect is the reason for the query run so slow.

Why is the reason of the total cost and how I can optimize it?

I already run `VACCUUM ANALYZE users` expecting the will improve the query, but it stayed the same.

Comment: You should do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` instead of just EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  Also, turn on track_io_timing first if possible.

Comment: If we take Rows Removed by Filter and multiply it by the 2 processes, we get almost the entirety of the stated size of the table.  So almost all rows have external_id/whitelabel_id = 18?

Comment: There are 1111475 index entries with value `18` for the column `whitelabel_id` that won't be *very* selective. The plan expect to read them all, discard 1111474 and keep 1. That's not efficient at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost is an estimate.  The high cost doesn't *cause* the query to be slow, it merely reflects the expectation that the query will be slow.  If the planner correctly estimates you will be filtering out so many rows, that is good reason to think it will be slow.

If you have separate indexes on both `(external_id, email)` and `(external_id, uuid)`, then you should be able to get a very efficient BitmapOr operation.  You apparently already have an index on `(external_id, email, uuid)`, so the that first one is covered, you would only have to add the 2nd.